# Helper.php File missing in yajra/local-Datatable/src folder

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access a project named UltimatePOS that was given to me, and whenever i try to access "localhost/UltimatePOS/public" i get the following error :

> Warning:
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\UltimatePOS\vendor\composer/../yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/helper.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UltimatePOS\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
>   66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\UltimatePOS\vendor\composer/../yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src/helper.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\UltimatePOS\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line
>   66

I tried looking for the file helper.php in `yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle/src` but apparently yajra folder seems to be empty.

Can i get any advice on how to solve and find `helper.php` file.?

Thanks
Best regards.

Comment: Did you run composer install?

Comment: I suppose the composer was already installed. I bought this php script and tried running it as it is. Do i have to install composer on it again.?

Comment: It wouldn't harm to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, composer install if there is a composer.lock in the original source code; otherwise I'd do a composer update.

From a detailed point of view, that file name looks like the typical Laravel helper file containing functions to use across the project/package. [More info about helpers](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers)